# Relation of current with frequency and voltage

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis

I tried to solve a numerical problem but I got stuck and I think it very necessary to have its solution. I will draw certain basic conclusions when I would found its solution.
The question is:

An incandescent lamp takes 2A from 220V and 60-cycles mains.If the lamp resistance is assumed to be constant what current will it take from:
1- 220V 25-cycle mains.
2- 110V 60-cycle mains.

Comment: 1) The same, 2) Half - it's got nothing to do with frequency if the resistance stays constant (which it doesn't on incandescent lamps but your question stated it should be constant).

Comment: This is a valid, on-topic question, with an answer that obviously isn't obvious to a newbie, so why should it be closed?

Answer (score 1):

If the lamp's resistance is assumed to be constant, then the current simply follows, in both cases, Ohm's law:

$$ \text{I} = \frac{\text{E}}{\text{R}}$$

However, the lamp's resistance will *NOT* remain constant, as indicated below:

[image]

Comment: How did you find the graph experimentally or theoratically @EM Fields?

Comment: Both. I used a voltmeter and an ammeter to measure the voltage across and current through a 100 watt incandescent lamp while I adjusted the voltage with a VARIAC, then  calculated the resistance using Ohm's law.  Except for the cold resistance, that is, which I measured with an ohmmeter.